# C++ memory management. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

I was asked this in an interview:
"In terms of memory management in C++, state everything that is wrong with this code?"

```
int main(){
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        delete foo; }
        }



class Foo{

    foo(){
        string x = new string;
        }
    }
```

I am new to C++ and OOP, so I was a bit stuck. Help?

Comment: I downvoted because I feel this question lacks two vital pieces of information: a proper [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (your code doesn't compile) and a **specific problem**. Are you having a specific problem with this code? Are you leaking memory and unsure why? Are you curious why deleting `Foo` doesn't clean up all memory it allocated? Did you read a website that had this code and assured you it's safe? With some [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33227066/edit) I feel this could be much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't compile for starters. In `string x = new string;` the types don't match. You are assigning a string* to a string variable. You need `string* x = new string;`.

Also `foo` isn't a constructor for `Foo` as the case isn't the same so you will have a missing return type error.

Then you are leaking a string object every time you construct a new object as delete is never called on the newed object.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not deleted, so there is memory leak in the code.